# Exclude one column in matching pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple columns

```
 ID|NAME|CITY|AGE|A Bot(S)_S|B Cost_S|C Value(!)_S|D Bot($)_S|E Value(!)_S
```

I am able to find the columns ending with '_S' using below code

```
 df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('_S')]
```

But i need one or more columns to be excluded example : 'D Bot($)_S' while fetching.

EDIT : Correction in column names , they are having space in between.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Can you be specific on *all* the columns that you will be working on? And this is a regular expression problem instead of pandas.

Comment: @Toukenize As mentioned in EDIT these are the sample columns having suffix as '_S' similarly there are some other set of columns with different suffixes out of which some columns needs to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This give you what you need (the regex reads as anything that does not start with `D`, followed by anything - denoted with `.*`, and lastly `_S`):

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^[^D].*_S')]
```

If you want to exclude something else that starts with `A` instead like `Auto Bot($)_S`, change the `D` to `A`

Comment: Thanks , a correction in the question , my actual column names have SPACE in between like 'Auto Bot($)_S' , when i am applying the solution given its not giving the desired result. could you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.filter(regex="[^D]_S")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

UPDATE:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r"^[^D].*_S")]
```

Comment: Thanks , a correction in the question , my actual column names have SPACE in between like 'Auto Bot($)_S' , when i am applying the solution given its not giving the desired result. could you please suggest

Comment: it is giving result but excluding all the columns having 'Auto' as starting where as i want only 'Auto Bot($)_S' to be excluded